# Drupal 7 - Error when updating the database

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I just started with drupal 7. After installation process, I want to include another database (new database has the same name, and it was used on another drupal project). Together with the database I have replaced sites folder.

The problem is, after I import a new database, on refresh I am redirected to install drupal. When I type database info I get error:

Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).

Any help is appreciated!
Denis

Answer (score 0):

If you database server is on the same machine as the web server, and you were using localhost as the address, try using 127.0.0.1 instead.